# Voip integration in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit

Can we integrate `VoIP` services through the new framework `CallKit` without using any server services or push notification?

I am really new to this concept, also checked the speaker box app as a sample app but didn't get much idea how it would be working.

Please, share your feedback if anyone has integrated `CallKit`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `CallKit` framework provides programmatic access to VoIP functionality, as well as call blocking and identification. Apps can use CallKit to receive incoming calls and make outgoing calls using the native phone UI.

[Reference for call kit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit).

**Can we integrate VoIP services through new framework call kit without using any server services or push notification?**

**No we can't use it**. You will need third parties like `Twilio`, `Plivo`, or `ICELink` and create your own server. Then provide `CallKit` the data required, it will handle the call and UI stuff. You can read the apple docs for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If a CallKit app only intends to make outgoing calls, then it may be possible to not have a server component. But if the app intends to receive incoming calls while the app may not be running (e.g. when it is suspended), those incoming calls must be signaled via Push Notification, and those push notifications are typically sent by a backing server.

Comment: How can I test voip calls. I am sorry but I am really new to this and I have speaker box app which is sample downloaded from dev.apple. Can you please guide me?

Comment: I add additional to Stuart's answer, "You can implement pushkit notification and create voip certificate in developer account."
And don't forgot to enable background modes for "VoIP" and "Audio Airplay"